# Unable to load JDK7 types in Android Studio

Tags: json, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, android-studio-3.0, objectmapper

I have being coming up with solutions to make this post successful, unfortunately I ended here with these error I've been aching to fix.

The error stated when I stated to implement *ObjectMapper*.

```
W/Java7Support: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"address":"jh...
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
W/System.err:     at store.pnp.com.pnp_store.ConfirmOrder.volleyCall(ConfirmOrder.java:250)
W/System.err:     at store.pnp.com.pnp_store.ConfirmOrder.access$800(ConfirmOrder.java:50)
W/System.err:     at store.pnp.com.pnp_store.ConfirmOrder$3.onClick(ConfirmOrder.java:190)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "store.pnp.com.pnp_store"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/javax.json-1.0.4.jar')


    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
}
```

My Volley uses the ObjectMapper to convert data into json formatted data, ready to be saved:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String URL = "http://....108:8080/order/service/save/order";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add( new CustomerOrder ( email, totalQuantity, cost, phoneNumber, address, closeShop, contact, orderStatus, orderDate, deliveryDate, order ) );

String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString( data );

Log.d( TAG, "Json:" + new JSONObject(arrayToJson));
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new JSONObject(arrayToJson),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                if ( response.length() <= 0 ){
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Order Successfully Created...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // handle error
                Log.d(TAG, "Error" + error + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage() );
            }
        });
```

I have searched for solutions, tried one/two and they did not work. I
also added the following lines in my gradle:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

How can I fix this error?